# Acumatica REST API error

Tags: rest, api, acumatica

I've been trying to get a simple Acumatica contract-based REST API GET call to work for many hours now, and all I'm getting is an error when it apparently times out: "A task was canceled.", with no inner exception. I've tried quite a few different examples trying to accomplish this with both .NET Core 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.7.1 , and always get this vague error. Note: The same calls in Postman work fine.

See the code below for my latest version of simplified code to try to just get something to work. The call to GetAsync is what hangs there for a couple of minutes and then throws the error.

```
var str = new StringContent(
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        new
        {
            name = "admin",
            password = "admin",
            company = "Company",
            branch = ""
        }),
        Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

string baseUrl = "http://localhost/AcuAmazon172040019";

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PostAsync(baseUrl + 
    "/entity/auth/login", str))
using (HttpResponseMessage res2 = await client.GetAsync(baseUrl + 
    "/entity/Default/6.00.001/salesorder/so/001337"))
using (HttpContent content = res2.Content)
{
    string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    if (data != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data);
    }
}
```

Acumatica v17.204.0019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you use (the endpoint, entity name and all parts of the entity key) are all case-sensitive.  Use "SalesOrder" instead of "salesorder" and probably "SO" instead of "so"

```
"/entity/Default/6.00.001/SalesOrder/SO/001337"
```

Comment: Wow, I'm very surprised, but happy, that it was as simple as this.  You're right, and it was working with Postman because I had the case correct.  I didn't think about this because a URL case typically doesn't matter, but I wasn't thinking about the class names and parameters being part of the path.  I wish the exception info was more informative.  Thanks much.

Comment: As I understand the implementation Acumatica returns the most specific thing you request, in this case a specific order. But if you request "../SalesOrder/SO/" you're request all SO-type orders. Or "../SalesOrder/" all sales orders. Because "../salesorder/" didn't exist in the dictionary of entities it was effectively attempting to return *everything* in the end-point hence the process hang and timing out. An error if no matching top-level entity would definitely be good though.